# Would a "credibility" tag be appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that a fair bit of questions could be tagged with "credibility" to signify that the asker is either trying to prove their credibility, or evaluate another's credibility.

That said, I'm new to this site, so I am curious to see what other seasoned members think of this.

Comment: Probably not in my opinion

Comment: You should include some questions which you think could be tagged with it. That would make it easier for the community to evaluate your proposal.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be useful.

Comment: I doubt it would be useful for anything other than inciting anger

Answer (score 2):

I think such a tag is probably too wide and would be a meta-tag (a tag that regroup different concrete independant tags), I'll give some example probably not complete but it'll give you an idea :

- Credibility about collegue/clients ? It's about socializing, handling conflicts, profesionalism and communication.
- Credibility about management ? It's more about visilibity and politics and profesionalism
- Credibility on higher level (CEO,...) ? politics